# Dev Express Layout Control Tab Order not going in order of Visual Studio's noted tab order. How to fix?

Tags: c#, devexpress, visual-studio-2010

I have a winform project that is using a devexpress layout control and I am using Visual Studio's tab order feature to set the tab order of the child controls in the layout control.  However, at runtime only the first child control in the layout control is hit when I hit the tab key.

Has anyone run into this problem, and know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the [LayoutControl.OptionsFocus.EnableAutoTabOrder](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraLayoutOptionsFocus_EnableAutoTabOrdertopic) property to false.